# First Occurence of a Field Pair in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like this:

```
+------------+---------------+--------+
|    City    | Category Name | Orders |
+------------+---------------+--------+
| London     | Components    |     29 |
| Woolston   | Bikes         |     16 |
| Union City | Clothing      |     13 |
| London     | Bikes         |     13 |
| Union City | Bikes         |     11 |
| Union City | Components    |     11 |
| Woolston   | Clothing      |     11 |
| Woolston   | Components    |      8 |
| Woolston   | Accessories   |      8 |
| Union City | Accessories   |      8 |
| London     | Clothing      |      4 |
| London     | Accessories   |      1 |
+------------+---------------+--------+
```

The goal is to get each city and its most popular category, so:

```
+------------+---------------+
|    City    | Category Name |
+------------+---------------+
| London     | Components    |
| Woolston   | Bikes         |
| Union City | Clothing      |
+------------+---------------+
```

In this case, I'd need to pick the first occurrence of each city in the first table along with its category.

I've tried using the standard:

```
SELECT City, Max(Orders) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY City
```

That however starts to become problematic as soon as you try to add the category name into the mix and I also do not want the `Orders` field in the new table.

Is there a way to do this nicely?

Comment: *"Is there a way to do this nicely?"* This dataset seams not to have equal values within a "group", but is it possible to have those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions or a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.orders = (select max(t2.orders) from t t2 where t2.city = t.city);
```

As a window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by city order by orders desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, correlated subquery was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select a.City, a.[Category Name]
    from   your_table a
    where  a.Orders = ( select max(Orders) 
                        from   your_table 
                        where  a.City = City );
```

Comment: Also worked perfectly - Gordon was faster though haha. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT City,category_name, order
FROM Table a where order in (select max(order) from table b where a.city=b.city)
```

Comment: That's fine only if every record on top of the table has a unique city. Had the fourth record's orders been 14 we'd have 2 Londons in the resulting table.

Answer (score 0):

This could be worth a try:

```
Select Distinct city, MaxCnt.category_name
from t
Cross APPLY(Select Top 1 t2.city, t2.category_name, Count(*) as RecCnt  from t t2 where t2.city = t.city Group BY t2.city, t2.category_name Order By RecCnt DESC) as MaxCnt
```